# SMTP ERROR in class.phpmailer.php

Tags: php, email, smtp

I have downloaded class.phpmailer.php, class.smtp.php and PHPMailerAutoload.php.

Error:

```
  ﻿  2014-06-21 15:24:30 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? (4296) SMTP connect() failed. Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.
```

PHP code to execute the smtp email with a given $email, $subject and $body.

```
<?php
    require_once("..\htmlphp\class.phpmailer.php");
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Eastern');
    include("..\htmlphp\class.smtp.php"); // optional, gets called from within class.phpmailer.php if not already loaded
     $mail = new PHPMailer();
     $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
     $mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                                       // 1 = errors and messages
                                       // 2 = messages only
     $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
     $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 // sets the prefix to the servier
     $mail->Host       = "smtp.live.com";      
     $mail->Port       = 587;                            
     $mail->Username   = "self@live.com"; 
     $mail->Password   = "pass1"; 
     $mail->From="self@live.com";
     $mail->Subject    = $subject;
     $mail->Body=$body;
     $mail->AddAddress($email);
     //$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer.gif");      // attachment
     //$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer_mini.gif"); // attachment
     if(!$mail->Send()) {
          echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
     } else {
          echo "Message sent!";
     }
?>
```

Comment: from which os you are trying to send email?

Comment: ssl uses port 465. tls uses 587.